# First-child pseudo selector issue with heading tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I got stuck when designing a dynamic page of news today when I added a heading tag at the beginning of my section and the first-child of a p tag inside a div stopped working.
This is what I was trying to do and it was working until I add the heading tag.

```css
.pubs .newsdate {
    border-top:1px solid rgb(255,179,0);
}
.pubs:first-child .newsdate {
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
    <h2>News</h2> //issue
    <div class="pubs">
        <p class="newsdate">stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pubs">
        <p class="newsdate">stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pubs">
        <p class="newsdate">stuff</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

The first border was being removed properly until I added the heading (h2) tag.
Then, the pseudo selector stopped working.
What could have happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.pubs:first-child` looks for a class of `pubs` **that is also the first child** of its parent element (in this case, parent element is class `content`. Once you add an `h2` element before the first `pubs` class, then `pubs` is no longer the *first* child, but the *second*.

Try `.pubs:first-of-type` instead:

```
.pubs:first-of-type .newsdate {
    border: none;
}
```

The `:first-of-type` pseudo-selector will look for the first **type** of whichever class or ID or element you prepend it with. By this, I mean that it doesn't matter if an element (`div`), a class (`.pub`), or an ID (`#pub`) comes before the pseudo-selector (each one is valid). Although it wouldn't make much sense to use an ID, since those are supposed to be unique.

Also notice I said first *type*, not first *instance* (two people have already commented (one deleted their comment) confusedly about what I'm saying). For instance, if you have class `.pubs` on three `div` elements and two `p` elements, your `:first-of-type` pseudo-selector would apply to the first `.pubs div` element **AND** the first `.pubs p` element.

So `first-of-type` pseudo-selector can apply to *multiple elements*, depending on how you use it.

If you think about it, this is a better solution than when you first had it working, because this solution looks specifically for the very first instance of the `.pubs` class, whereas your example only works circumstantially (when there isn't anything before `.pubs`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I REALLY didn't now that I was looking for the first-child of the PARENT element. I always thought as the first occurrence of that element. This completely changes my view of this pseudo-selector. I wonder how many people still think the same way I used to. Thanks again!

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira Check out this [cool game](http://flukeout.github.io/) for testing your knowledge on pseudo-selectors. It's short, fun, and invaluable!

Comment: "The :first-of-type pseudo-selector will look for the first type of whichever class or ID or element you prepend it with." No, it looks for the first of its *type*, i.e. in this case div. It has nothing to do with class or ID - that it works is a coincidence because every `.pubs` is a div. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107

Comment: @BoltClock That is what I meant (I even said "type" in my answer); you can type `.pubs` or `#pubs` or `div` before the pseudo-selector, all would be valid for `<div ID="pubs" class="pubs">`. I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) to avoid this.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxCwa/)

```
.pubs:first-of-type .newsdate {
    border:none;
}
```