# css select first element with specific tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make a css class that would give a background color to the first found element with a specific tag..

This **CSS**

```
.blue p:first-of-type {
    background-color:#2E9AFE;
}
```

Works for **example 1**:

```
<div class="blue">
    <p>element 1</p>
    <p>element 2</p>
    <p>element 2</p>
</div>
```

Doesn't work for **example 2**:

```
<div class="blue">
    <ul>
        <li><p>Parent 1</p>
            <ul>
                 <li><p>Element 1.1</p></li>
                <li><p>Element 1.2</p></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

In example 2, first element with tag `p` is `Parent 1`, however my code colors every element. Why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/CYX32/1/

Comment: The `:first-of-type` selector selects the first of type contained within its parent element. In each case, the `p` is the first of type within their `li` elements.

Comment: @Alexandru Severian as like this you want this http://jsfiddle.net/CYX32/16/

Comment: Apparently wrong is this block-of-answers ‘marked as duplicate by andrewsi, kapa css May 29 '14 at 15:03 ..already has answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371669/first-child-pseudo-selector-issue-with-heading-tag ’ as this new above Q's ‘example 2’ with nested ul/ol shows this is Q is {tougher: find {the 1st or all} greatest grand-parent(s) of a particular type but NOT decedents} +{top solutions/answers: via pure CSS NOT hard-coded for the particular nesting levels} not yet given. So if block is wrong as likely, pls remove it & appropriately score-down those who did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:first-of-type` selector selects the first of type contained within its parent element. In each case, the `p` is the first of type within their `li` elements.

If you wish to select the first of type `p` within the first of type `li` within the first of type `ul` you're going to have to use the following selector:

```css
.blue > ul:first-of-type > li:first-of-type > p:first-of-type {
    background-color:#2E9AFE;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CYX32/18/).

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin unfortunately I think the only way you could realistically achieve that would be to introduce some JavaScript to pull the very first matching element. Even the Selectors Level 4 documentation does not introduce anything that would allow us to do this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to color the first occurence of `p` tag. and you don't know where exactly it is then I think the only way is to use javascript.

**Javascript**:

```
var blue = document.getElementsByClassName('blue')[0];
var p = blue.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
p.className = 'blueContent';
```

**CSS**

```
.blueContent {
    background-color:#2E9AFE;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYX32/26/)**

Comment: OP knows exactly where it is and didn't ask for a JS solution or include a JS tag, and there's a CSS-only answer. Why are you giving a JS solution?

Comment: @TylerH In this case, OP knows where it is but he/she had also asked what if the place is don't know in JamesDonnelly posts.. I don't know why OP removed that comment.

Comment: @Mr_Green I removed the comment because I saw your answer and didn't want JamesDonnelly to bother explaining the same thing. Thank you for your answer, it gave me a good alternative.

Comment: I see. Well, if you want to edit it, I'll remove my downvote :-) Otherwise it is stuck

Comment: @TylerH what should I edit? I didn't get you.. I introduced javascript but not any plugins related to it.. and also I explained when to use my solution. I definitely think my post is valid here. your downvote doesn't bother me :)

Comment: I just meant introduce an edit of some kind(add a word or embolden something), not semantically changing the answer, since SO locks in votes after a time unless a post is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
.blue > ul > li > p {
    background-color:#2E9AFE;
}
```

Comment: WHile code only answers are good, it would be greate if you explained what this code did

Answer (score 1):

Can you use jQuery to solve this? Here's one way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.blue').each(function(index, obj){
        var $p = $(this).find('p').eq(0);
        $p.css('background-color', '#2e9afe');
    })
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuuHs/1/)